# Комбинация (серия) поворотов вокруг произвольных точек

Tags: c#, матрицы, графика, 2d, рисование

Имеется объект некоторой фигуры, скажем отрезка прямой. Причем центр этого отрезка это центр начала координат. Также хранятся матрицы сдвига и поворота для этой прямой (если её необходимо визуализировать, то в соответствующий метод рисования подаётся произведение исходных координат на матрицы преобразований). Поворот осуществляется вокруг заданной точки на заданный угол.

**Собственно вопрос:** как задавать комбинацию поворотов в такой ситуации? Пробовал умножать матрицу текущего поворота на матрицу предыдущего (и наоборот), но ничего хорошего из этого не получил.

Comment: Класс [Matrix](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix?view=netframework-4.8) смотрели?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov решил проблему обновлением матрицы сдвига после поворота относительно произвольной точки и созданием новой матрицы поворота относительно начала координат.